# Audio analysis and feature extraction for music visualization

Tags: visualization, audio-analysis

I have a general question regarding how I should proceed with my music visualization endeavors. I am interested in visualizing classical music pieces, either recorded or live. I have used so far Processing, but I am open to other software or programming languages, too. Since my background is musicology and music theory, I would like to incorporate music theoretical concepts or any tools that MIR research has made available in analyzing music, so that I could create visualizations based on them.

However, I don't really know from where to start. I feel like I would like to study MIR concepts, but I feel it can become very technical and it seems that I don't need to be knowledgeable about all facets of MIR research. For example I want to analyze and visualize music, but not to synthesize. Or, could it be that learning about sound synthesis would also help me with my visualizations? And to what extent?

Alternatively, would it be better, to just pick some software/language and try its specific libraries for audio analysis??

Basically my dilemma is whether I should start with MIR theory or there is an alternative way of getting a good overview of all the features that one could maybe extract from a music piece, in order to have a richer palette for visualizations.

If you could give me some advice on this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks, Ilias

Comment: check out max/msp or pure-data
specifically their audio-processing capabilities

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have already started digging into max/msp